# Is there any way as of today to instruct openapi-generator to add a Header and a fixed Header Value for a particular HTTP request in the client code?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I need the generated clients to forward a fixed Key Value pair as the Header. The generated client library should not have the Header as a method input. I expect the library to add the Header and Header value automatically.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEDB2.jpg]

As per the Constant Parameter documentation, I have tried adding below in the OpenAPI Document parameters section.

```json
        {
          "name": "X-CUSTOM-HEADER",
          "in": "header",
          "schema": {
            "type" : "string",
            "enum" : ["FIXED_VALUE"]
          },
          "required" : true
```

This adds the "X-CUSTOM-HEADER" as an argument to the method. My expectation is that generated library code should hard code this value.

Comment: Filed feature request : https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of posting this question there was no way in [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate code that hardcodes the value of contants.
Filed feature request : https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16547
Also, Contributed in the implementation for Java(OkHttp) code generation :  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/16550
As of today, We can use `autosetConstants` property to automatically hardcode the constants in the generated code. Property name is subject to change but the plan is to support this feature. Support for `const` keyword is also planned.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `default` keyword in the schema.

```json
{
          "name": "X-CUSTOM-HEADER",
          "in": "header",
          "schema": {
            "type" : "string",
            "enum" : ["FIXED_VALUE"],
            "default": "FIXED_VALUE"
          },
          "required" : true
}
```

Comment: This also does not work. Also, The documentation mentions that "default" is only for the Server. If the client does not pass the value then server will use the default value. Also, Using Default with Required may not make sense because if the parameter is marked as required then the client always has to send a value and there is no need for a default value on the server.